# CSS ID not working / beginner issue

Tags: html, css

I am currently having a CSS problem and I hope someone can help me since I am a very beginner. 
I am trying to overlay and image over another image.

When I use inline code it works fine, for example:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/440/screenshot7cx.jpg/

```
    <div class="one_half">
    <div id="square_icon" style="position: absolute; top: 12%; left: 36%;"><img src="img/square_icon.png" width="77" height="76" /></div>
    <img src="img/square.jpg" width="412" height="145" />
    </div>
```

But if I try to insert in my CSS file direct it not work.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/screenshot8gvh.jpg/

```
    <style>
    #square_icon { position: absolute; top: 12%; left: 36%; };
    </style>
```

Why it not working when I include in my CSS file? Again I am sorry I am very amateur but I hope someone can help me understand this issue.

Thank you alot,
Patrick

Comment: The proper form is <style type="text/css"></style>

Comment: Also I think the last semi-colon is not required...

Comment: @Adam: The `type` attribute is not required, but the `<style>` tags should not be in a stylesheet.

Comment: I hope you don't have `<style>` tags in you CSS file. Also make sure you include it correctly (which you don't show).

Comment: You might find the CSS validator useful for debugging issues like this: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate-by-input, also most browsers have an error console which usually tells you when things are  wrong. In Chrome => settings -> developer tools -> console...

Comment: @Adam - the type attribute is not required if using the HTML5 doctype, where it's assumed to be text/css.

Comment: @JohnMcCollum Sorry I'm too set in my ways with HTML4.01 strict :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to style the div by id, you should give it an ID:

```
<div class="one_half">
    <div id="square_icon" style="position: absolute; top: 12%; left: 36%;"><img src="img/square_icon.png" width="77" height="76" /></div>
    <img src="img/square.jpg" width="412" height="145" />
</div>
```

and not a class

The corresponding styles:

```
<style>
    #square_icon { 
      position: absolute;
      top: 12%;
      left: 36%; 
    }//there is no ';' here
</style>
```

Also you made a mistake as mentioned above.

Comment: *"you should give it an ID [...] and not a class"* I don't see any difference to the OP's HTML. The div already has an ID. *"or change the selector to class selector"* You still have an ID selector... it's unclear what you want to say with this answer. Your code does not seem to match your words.

Comment: Dear all - thank you very much for the outstanding and fast replies. And thank you very much Jannis!  }//there is no ';' here <- this solved the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `<style>` tags in your CSS file.

You also should remove the semi-colon (`;`) from the end of your class

Remove them and this should work fine, as long as the CSS is linked to the HTML file correctly.

```
<head>     
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="/Style/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />    
</head>
```

---

If I've misunderstood, and your CSS styles are actually in your `<head>` tag like:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #square_icon { position: absolute; top: 12%; left: 36%; }
    </style>
</head>
```

Then try changing this to:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #square_icon { position: absolute; top: 12%; left: 36%; }
    </style>
</head>
```

Notice I've added `type="text/css"` to your `<style>` tag.

Comment: -1  -work fine? Did you even look at this and see the two mistakes?

Comment: @Jannis M: You seem to have misunderstood both the question and this answer.

Comment: @JannisM I didn't see the `;` at the end first time, cheers. Not worthy of a downvote in my opinion, but thanks anyway